# iText Pdf Page Byte Size

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a business requirement that requires me to splits pdfs into multiple documents.
Lets say I have a 100MB pdf, I need to split that into for simplicity sake, into multiple pdfs no larger than 10MB a piece.

I am using iText.

I am going to get the original pdf, and loop through the pages, but how can I determine the file size of each page without writing it separately to the disk?

Sample code for simplicity

```
int numPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

PdfImportedPage page;
for (int currentPage = 0; currentPage < numPages; ){
    ++currentPage;
    //Get page from reader
    page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, currentPage);

// I need the size in bytes here of the page

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to write it to the disk and delete it afterwards:

```
Document document = new Document();
File f= new File("C:\\delete.pdf");  //for instance
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(f));
document.open();
document.add(page);
document.close();
long filesize = f.length();   //this is the filesize in byte
f.delete();
```

I'm not absolutely sure, I admit, but I don't know how it should be possible to figure out the filesize if the file is not existing.

Comment: Right, I just wanted to call something like page.size.  I am going to have to do this for a very large number of documents and my end result is to just have 10 files, and didn't want to have to create 100 files to determine appropriate sizes.  But it looks like that is what I need to do.  Thanks!!