# Get size (in bytes) of a specific page in a PDF using iText

Tags: java, itext

I'm using iText (v 2.1.7) and I need to find the size, in bytes, of a **specific page**.

I've written the following code:

```
public static long[] getPageSizes(byte[] input) throws IOException {
        PdfReader reader;
        reader = new PdfReader(input);
        int pageCount = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        long[] pageSizes = new long[pageCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
            pageSizes[i] = reader.getPageContent(i+1).length;
        }

        reader.close();
        return pageSizes;
    }
```

But it doesn't work properly. The `reader.getPageContent(i+1).length;` instruction returns very small values (`<= 100` usually), even for large pages that are more than 1MB, so clearly this is not the correct way to do this.

But what IS the correct way? Is there one?

Note: I've already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641250/itext-pdf-page-byte-size), but the offered solution consists of writing each page of the PDF to disk and then checking the file size, which is extremely inefficient and may even be wrong, since I'm assuming this would repeat the PDF header and metadata each time. I was searching for a more "proper" solution.

Comment: you mean the size of the raw pdf code? or byte size of the text on the page? that'd only count actual text, not pictures of text.

Comment: @Marc B: indeed, I need the size of the entire PDF object that represents the page, including images.

Comment: Should the parts of the PDF that are not specific to a given page be counted or not?

Comment: The question reveals a lack of understanding of PDF. Pages have many shared resources, such as fonts, Image and Form XObjects. If you'd think of the size of a page, would you also include the entries of the objects used by that page in the xref table? And what about the page tree and the structure tree? Do you consider those part of the page? It is funny how you try to measure the size of a page by getting the content stream. You don't take any image or font into account when you do that. There is no correct way to know the size of one page due to the very nature of PDF.

Comment: You might want to read **Part 1** of my answer to the question [Why does combining PDFs make filesize balloon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123352)

Comment: Besides the question which cannot be answered, you do know that your iText version is very old? Version `7.0.1` came out last week.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I understand what you're saying, however I don't really see why that would prevent me from knowing the size of a page? Yes, the page is made up of several objects (some even referenced from other pages maybe), but can't we compute the size by adding up the sizes of all the objects? That's what I'm trying to do basically. As for the rationale behind it: I have a pre-existing program that accepts pdf attachments as imput, but has a limit of "1MB per page". Unfortunately this program is a "black box", and I cannot modify it, so I don't know how exactly it computes page sizes.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse - I know but unfortunately, due to company policies, we can only use libraries that are approved and available in our internal Maven repository, and 2.1.7 is the latest one on there. Believe me, I'd use the newer one if I could, you have no idea of the hassle I went through converting HTML to PDF using 2.xx, it's agony.

Comment: @ScottHunter - yes, they should be counted. Everything that makes up the page. Basically, I want the size of the final PDF file if I were to write the single page as a complete PDF document to disk (which I know how to do with iText, but I was searching for a more resource-friendly solution, as writing every page to disk as a separate document just to get the size seems a bit overkill)

Comment: Instead of writing to disk, you can write to memory. That's a lot faster but obviously there is a tradeoff for memory consumption.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse - it's what I had figured out, see my answer to this question. Tho I'm still wondering if there's a more efficient way, maybe by going through the dictionary returned by getPageN() and recursively resolving object references and adding up the total size. Seems more trouble than it's worth tho, since in the end what I needed was much simpler (again, see my answer).

Comment: Sometimes the brute force approach really is simplest. If you want it to go faster, just download more RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the end I managed to get hold of the source code for the original program that I was working with, which only accepted PDFs as input with a maximum "page size" of 1MB. Turns out... what it actually means by "page size" was `fileSize / pageCount` -_-^

For anyone that actually needs the precise size of a "standalone" page, with all content included, I've tested this solution and it seems to work well, tho it probably isn't very efficient as it writes out an entire PDF document for each page. Using a memory stream instead of a disk-based one helps, but I don't know how much.

```
public static int[] getPageSizes(byte[] input) throws IOException {
        PdfReader reader;
        reader = new PdfReader(input);
        int pageCount = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        int[] pageSizes = new int[pageCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
            try {
                Document doc = new Document();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PdfCopy copy= new PdfCopy(doc, bous);
                doc.open();
                PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, i+1);
                copy.addPage(page);
                doc.close();
                pageSizes[i] = bous.size();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        return pageSizes;
    }
```

Comment: Do keep in mind that you basically defined page-size as everything needed to render the page on it's own. The pdf with all the pages can be a lot smaller due to resource re-use, or possibly larger when it contains objects that are not rendered on any page. @Bruno is right in stating that there is no real pagesize definition in pdf due to the way the spec is written.

Comment: You can reduce memory requirements by using a `new CountingOutputStream(new NullOutputStream())` (both classes in Apache commons-io) instead of that `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Cool, didn't know of that utility stream, can come in handy, thanks